# Maximum of Multiple Named Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, range, max, named

I am having a lot of trouble with this one. I want to replicate this value in VBA:

```
=MAX(MAX(Named_Range1),MAX(Named_Range2),MAX(Named_Range3))
```

I am having an impossible time trying to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to place the formula in one of the cells and calculate the result in VBA code, you can also use the following code:

```
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
Dim y As Double

Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("Named_Range1").RefersToRange
Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Names("Named_Range2").RefersToRange
Set rng3 = ThisWorkbook.Names("Named_Range3").RefersToRange

y = WorksheetFunction.Max(rng1, rng2, rng3)
```

If named ranges are in another workbook, replace `ThisWorkbook` with `Workbooks("workbook name")`

Answer (score 1):

If the three ranges are in the same sheet then:

```
Sub MaxMax()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Union(Range(Named_Range1), Range(Named_Range2), Range(Named_Range3))
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(r)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For the result to be placed in F9, please try:

```
Sub Maximal()
   Range("F9").Formula = "=MAX(MAX(Named_Range1),MAX(Named_Range2),MAX(Named_Range3))"
End Sub
```

Comment: The inner `MAX` functions are redundant, so the equivalent would be `"=MAX(Named_Range1,Named_Range2,Named_Range3)"`